# Delphi: TStringList.Contains?

Tags: delphi, find, compare, tstringlist

Is there any integrated solution in Delphi 2007 to check whether a TStringList **contains** a part of a certain value?

e.g.:

```
List.AddObject('This is a string', customStringObject1); 
List.AddObject('This is a mushroom', customStringObject2); 
List.AddObject('Random stuff', customStringObject3);
```

Searching for *"This is a"* is supposed to deliver me "true", since the first two elements contain this partwise.

The only method i'm aware of so far is `TStringList.find(string,integer)`, but this performs a complete string comparision, i.e. only searching for *This is a string* will return true.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not integrated, but you can use the Pos function on the Text property:

```
Pos('This is a', List.Text)
```

And if you want it to be integrated, you can create a class helper for TStrings.

Answer (score 5):

Not directly, no.  You would have to either:

1) call `Pos()` on the `Text` property, which is not efficient if you have a lot of strings.

2) loop through the list manually, calling `Pos()` on each `String`.  More efficient, but also more coding.

3) derive a new class from `TStringList` and override its virtual `CompareStrings()` method to compare strings however you want (the default implementation simple calls `AnsiCompareStr()` or `AnsiCompareText()`, depending on the `CaseSensitive` property).  Return 0 if you find a match.  You can then use the `TStringList.Find()` method, which calls `CompareStrings()` internally (be careful, so does `TStringList.Sort()`, but you can avoid that if you call `TStringList.CustomSort()` instead).

Answer (score 0):

As Toon Krijthe mentioned, a class helper could be an elegant solution:

```pascal
    TStringsHelper = class helper for TStrings
        function Contains(const s:string): Boolean;
    end;
    
    
    function TStringsHelper.Contains(const s:string): Boolean;
    begin
        Result := self.IndexOf(s) <> -1;
    end;
```

Than you can call:

```pascal
    if list.Contains('some text') then
     ...
```